# The value held by 'short int' get overflowed, but not with 'auto'?

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long maximum = 0;
    unsigned long values[] = {60000, 50, 20, 40, 0};
    
    for(short value : values){
        cout << "Current value:" << value << "\n";

        if(value > maximum)
            maximum = value;
    }
    cout << "Maximum value is: " << maximum;
    
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs are:

```
Current value:-5536
Current value:50
Current value:20
Current value:40
Current value:0
Maximum value is: 18446744073709546080
```

I know I should not use `short` inside `for` loop, better use `auto`, but I was just wondering, what is going on here?

I'm using Ubuntu with `g++ 9.3.0` I believe.

Comment: What you are seeing is the effects of integer overflow. This is happening in two places, where you try and store a number in `value` that is bigger than the variable can hold, and when you implicitly convert a negative `value` to an unsigned quantity in order to compare it with `maximum`.

Comment: @drescherjm... on the OP's platform.

Comment: In the loop, `value` has type `short`.   Behaviour is undefined if any of the elements of `values` exceeds what a `short` can represent.  A `short` is not guaranteed to be able to represent values above `32767`.   Last I checked, `60000` exceeds that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with `short value` when element `60000` is reached.

That's too big to fit into a `short` on your platform, so your `short` is overflowed, with implementation-defined results.

What seems to be happening in your case is that `60000` wraps round to the negative `-5536`, then converted (in a well-defined) way to an `unsigned long`, which in your case is 2<sup>64</sup> - 5536: that's equal to the maximum displayed by your program.

One fix is to use the idiomatic

```
for(auto&& value: values){
```

Comment: FWIW, initialization with an out of bounds value is not UB, it's implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Since when? Am I out of date again? I'll change the answer blindly since you're normally correct when we have these head-to-heads.

Comment: I'll change back for now. Methinks C++20 defines it: not before then?

Comment: Since always?  It's at least in the C++11 standard: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#16.8 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv#integral-3

Comment: And why the C++ standards committee won't allow `for(value : values)` in place of `for(auto&& value : values)` is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty much simple, the 2-bytes `short` type integer can hold only the values between -32,768 to 32,767. Afterwards, it get overflowed. You've given 60000, which is obviously an overflow for a `short int`.

When you use `auto` here, the `value` get converted into an appropriate type which could hold such a large number (note that it's up to the platform in which you're running the program.)

In my case, the `value` is get converted into `unsigned long` which ranges between 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: `unsigned long` is clearly bigger than that on the OP's platform else the output cannot be accounted for. And the range you cite for a `short` applies to a 16 bit 2's complement `short`. Again it can be larger than that (or 1's complement / signed magnitude up to but not including C++20).